# MVC 6 Areas and multiple login pages redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'd been searching for a solution to this problem for quite a long time but unfortunately haven't found any nice and elegant way to handle it.

Here are the details:

1. My MVC 6 application use Areas. Each area has separate directories for the Controllers, Views etc.
2. Authentication is based on the standard out of the box web application template with user accounts stored in sql server
3. What I want to achieve is:

   - When user enters /AreaA/Restricted/Page then he is redirected into /AreaA/Account/Login
   - When user enters /AreaB/Restricted/Page then he is redirected into /AreaB/Account/Login etc...
4. Even though I can change the stanard login page redirect from "/Account/Login" into something different like this:

   ```
   services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options=> {
       options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = 
           new Microsoft.AspNet.Http.PathString("/HardcodedAreaName/Account/Login");
   });
   ```

I am not able to redirect into different actions/login pages for each area.

Prior to MVC 6 I was able to use AuthorizeAttribute with url parameter:

```
public class CustomAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }

        // redirect to login page with the original url as parameter.
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(Url + "?returnUrl=" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
        }

    }
```

and then passing the area dependent url by decorating each controller:

```
[CustomAuthorization(Url = "/Admin/Account/Login"]
public class AdminAreaController : Controller
{ ...
```

But it does not work anymore :(

Comment: Did you ever end up getting this working? How did you put the changes in the `Configure` method since `services` is not available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following and see if it works (I did try this and it works fine, but not sure If I have covered all scenarios):

The place where you register you `CookieAuthentication` middleware, you can do something like

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.LoginPath = "/area1/login1";
    o.AuthenticationScheme = "scheme1";
    //TODO: set other interesting properties if you want to
});

app.UseCookieAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.LoginPath = "/area2/login2";
    o.AuthenticationScheme = "scheme2";
    //TODO: set other interesting properties if you want to
});
```

On you controller/action, specify the authentication scheme..example:

```
[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "scheme1")]
public IActionResult Test1()
{
    return Content("Test1");
}

[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "scheme2")]
public IActionResult Test2()
{
    return Content("Test2");
}
```

Comment: Hi Kiran. Thank you for your effort. The solution you proposed is almost fine except one thing...

When trying to configure the cookieauthentication the way you proposed, only the last option is saved. 

So if I do like this:
app.UseCookieAuthentication(o =>
{   o.LoginPath = "/area1/login1";
    o.AuthenticationScheme = "scheme1";});
{   o.LoginPath = "/area2/login2";
    o.AuthenticationScheme = "scheme2";});

scheme1 / loginpath 1 are ignored and application can only see scheme2 and login path 2. 

Could you show exactly how did you applied both options in your Startup.cs file?

Comment: Hmm...I already shared the code above for setting the options above...could you share how your Startup.cs file looks like?

Comment: Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...

  // "Front" area - This option is ignored
  services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(o =>
  {
   o.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Front/Account/Login";
   o.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AuthenticationScheme = "FrontAuthScheme";
   });

  
  // "Admin" area - This option works fine but overrides the previous one
  services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(o =>
  {
   o.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Admin/Account/Login";
   o.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AuthenticationScheme = "AdminAuthScheme";
   });

}

Comment: Your settings are different than what I mentioned above... I used the settings on CookieAuthentication middleware and not on IdentityOptions...

Comment: You're definetly right Kiran. I moved option setting from ConfigureServices method into Configure and now it works :-) Thanks!

Comment: Just one more issue - I had discovered that although redirecting works fine, my Login method is not signing users anymore. Even though I log in in properly, I am being constantly redirected to login page. Any idea? Here's how I sign in:
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

Comment: are you able to login in now ? I am also facing the same issue.